# can populate the picker view but not get data from it

Tags: ios, objective-c, uipickerview

I have three different UIPickerViews in one view/viewcontroller. Instead of making the viewController the delegate and datasource for all three UIPickerViews, I created separate subclass files for each of the UIPickerViews and imported those files into the viewController. I created outlets (click and dragging from storyboard) for each of the UIPickerViews in the ViewController. Therefore, in viewDidLoad of the viewController, I connected the outlet to the datasource/delegates. Here is one example with the outlet for self.timePicker

```
self.timePicker.delegate = [self timePickerDataDelegate];
self.timePicker.dataSource = [self timePickerDataDelegate];
```

where `[self timePickerDataDelegate]` calls the constructor

```
-(TimePicker *)timePickerDataDelegate
{

    if (!_timePickerDataDelegate) _timePickerDataDelegate = [[TimePicker alloc] init];
    return _timePickerDataDelegate;
}
```

In the timePicker class, I implemented the required methods for it to serve as the delegate and datasource. Indeed, when I run the app all three of the UIPickerViews are populated with the correct data. However, I'm having a problem getting the data from the picker view.  Since my UIPickerViews are in a modal view, I try to get the data in `prepareForSegue`, which gets called when the modal is dismissed. However, when I do this to get the time value selected I get the error

```
  No visible interface for UIPickerView declares the selector pickerView:titleForRow:forComponent

 NSString *time = [self.timePicker pickerView:self.timePicker titleForRow:[self.timePicker selectedRowInComponent:0] forComponent:0];
```

Can you explain what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method `pickerView:titleForRow:forComponent:` is a method of the `UIPickerViewDelegate`, not the `UIPickerView`.

The line:

```
NSString *time = [self.timePicker pickerView:self.timePicker titleForRow:[self.timePicker selectedRowInComponent:0] forComponent:0];
```

should be:

```
NSString *time = [self.timePickerDataDelegate pickerView:self.timePicker titleForRow:[self.timePicker selectedRowInComponent:0] forComponent:0];
```

or:

```
NSString *time = [self.timePicker.delegate pickerView:self.timePicker titleForRow:[self.timePicker selectedRowInComponent:0] forComponent:0];
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that the first element in the method should actually be the delegate

```
self.timePickerDataDelegate
```

and the other elements the outlets

```
self.timePicker
```

Here it is in full

```
   NSString *time = [self.timePickerDataDelegate pickerView:self.timePicker titleForRow:`[self.timePicker selectedRowInComponent:0] forComponent:0];`
```